# PHP can't retrieve cookie on one page

Tags: php, cookies, internationalization

My website has two languages (English and German) between which a user can chose by clicking a button. It then sets a cookie to store this decision for `24h`. I'm also using the `php-i18n` class from `GitHub`. It works by storing all language texts in specific `*.ini` files. According to the chosen language, either the German or English text gets displayed via `PHP` variables. I hope I explained it well enough.

That all works, except for my "legal details" page. Since this page has a lot of text, I made two versions of this one page, one English, one German. Depending on what language is chosen, I want to display the according page version. But it somehow always ends up being the "default German" version. I'm probably missing something very obvious as to why my code isn't working.

**`PHP`** in the header (dynamic, shows up on all pages before all else):

```
require_once 'i18n.class.php';
$i18n = new i18n('lang/lang_{LANGUAGE}.ini', 'langcache/', 'de');
// Parameters: language file path, cache dir, default language (all optional)
$i18n->setForcedLang('de');

// language buttons & set cookie
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  $lang=$_GET['lang'];
  if ($lang == 'de') {
    $i18n->setForcedLang('de');
    setcookie('language', 'lang-de', time() + 86400, '/');
    echo "german cookie set!";
  }
  if ($lang == 'en') {
    $i18n->setForcedLang('en');
    setcookie('language', 'lang-en', time() + 86400, '/');
    echo "english cookie set!";
  }
}

// get language cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language']== "lang-de") {
  echo "german cookie is really set, now get it!";
  $i18n->setForcedLang('de');
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language']== "lang-en") {
  echo "english cookie is really set, now get it!";
  $i18n->setForcedLang('en');

} else {
  echo "no cookie set";
}

// init object: load language files, parse them if not cached, and so on.
$i18n->init();
```

**`PHP`** on the legal details page:

```
include 'templates/header.php';

// show english or german legal details
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  $lang=$_GET['lang'];
  if ($lang == 'de') {
    echo "k, german impressum";
    include 'impressum-de.php';
  } else if ($lang == 'en') {
    echo "english impressum";
    include 'impressum-en.php';
  }
} else if ($language == 'de') {
  echo "german impressum b/c cookie";
  include 'impressum-de.php';
} else if ($language == 'en') {
  echo "english impressum b/c cookie";
  include 'impressum-en.php';
} else {
  echo "default German impressum";
  include 'impressum-de.php';
}
```

The buttons:

```
<div class="language">
  <a href="?lang=de" name="lang-de" class="lang-de">DE</a>/
  <a href="?lang=en" name="lang-en" class="lang-en">EN</a>
</div>
```

Does anyone have some input? Ideas how to improve the code are also always much appreciated since I'm still learning.

Comment: I think the cookie setting is correct, your issue somewhere else in your code

Comment: Could the issue be with the links, then? (I'll add it to my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:  (not "else if" -> its "elseif")

```
include 'templates/header.php';

// show english or german legal details
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  $lang=$_GET['lang'];
  if ($lang == 'de') {
    echo "k, german impressum";
    include 'impressum-de.php';
  } elseif ($lang == 'en') {
    echo "english impressum";
    include 'impressum-en.php';
  }
} elseif ($language == 'de') {
  echo "german impressum b/c cookie";
  include 'impressum-de.php';
} elseif ($language == 'en') {
  echo "english impressum b/c cookie";
  include 'impressum-en.php';
} else {
  echo "default German impressum";
  include 'impressum-de.php';
}
```